# Remove rows and replace char in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

l have a csv file of 2000 rows that l process with pandas

```
id                                          raw_value   manual_raw_value
00037625-4706-4dfe-a7b3-de8c47e3a28d        3/          3\
000b08e3-4129-4fd2-8ec0-23d00fe38a45        ok          ok
002882ca-48bb-4161-a75a-cf0ec984d650        ab%cd       100%
005ce267-674a-418c-b0f6-7835fdf02219        14:17       14:17
0070ae6a-944b-4549-a229-00301cc96e29        6456        14762
00827aad-f737-4ec6-9881-988982662ad8        HT          HT
008796d7-b21e-4b91-854f-1d163e336c05        Avenue      Avenue
009dfaa8-5343-4345-8619-3010a1f77a03        1740        1740
00ad9cc7-c048-4d82-aa90-727d6eede4ea        Total       Total
00c46967-ee13-40ac-a4b4-4c0cf4186e90        ST          ST
01167f7e-01eb-4033-b62b-92674ba40182        LA          LA
013254c9-4353-45dc-9955-7520474803b7        zébra       zébra
01662fca-8d52-40a6-be17-59e5e51c4ac2        31,40       31,40
01666c4c-8b9e-4081-9b9c-5c75f9a1736d        143.23      143.23
0167ac66-fcd5-43da-95fa-c38107860a8d        restitut-ion    res_titution
```

l want to remove  the rows from this csv (and store them  in new csv file) as follow :

1. remove each row that contains in `raw_value` or `manual_raw_value` this char `{ , ; : \ / . $ € %  _ -}`
2. make all letters to lowercase
3. replace `é` and `è` by `e`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and values with `|` (regex `or`), then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and last apply [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html):

```
a = [ '\,', ';', '\:', '\\\\', '\/', '\.', '\$', '€', '\%', '_', '-']
joined = "|".join(a)

mask = ~df['raw_value'].str.contains(joined) | 
       ~df['manual_raw_value'].str.contains(joined)
cols = ['raw_value','manual_raw_value'] 
df = df[mask].replace(['é','è'],'e', regex=True) 
             .apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()) 
             .reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
                                     id raw_value manual_raw_value
0  000b08e3-4129-4fd2-8ec0-23d00fe38a45        ok               ok
1  0070ae6a-944b-4549-a229-00301cc96e29      6456            14762
2  00827aad-f737-4ec6-9881-988982662ad8        ht               ht
3  008796d7-b21e-4b91-854f-1d163e336c05    avenue           avenue
4  009dfaa8-5343-4345-8619-3010a1f77a03      1740             1740
5  00ad9cc7-c048-4d82-aa90-727d6eede4ea     total            total
6  00c46967-ee13-40ac-a4b4-4c0cf4186e90        st               st
7  01167f7e-01eb-4033-b62b-92674ba40182        la               la
8  013254c9-4353-45dc-9955-7520474803b7     zebra            zebra
```

Comment: l got an error at this line df = df[mask].replace(['é','è'],'e', regex=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).reset_index(drop=True).    File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 1841, in _make_str_accessor
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string "
AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Ok, then need `df = df[mask].astype(str).replace(['é','è'],'e', regex=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 0):

using applymap one can do this

```
df[['raw_value', 'manual_raw_value']] =  df[['raw_value', 'manual_raw_value']][~df[['raw_value', 'manual_raw_value']].applymap(lambda x: any([xx in ['{', ',', ';', ':', '\\', '/', '.', '$', '€', '%','_','-','}'] for xx in x]))]

# here I apply applymap to the two columns and see if any of special characters are in each element. this will replace all the items of the two columns that have special character by NaN

df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any', inplace = True)
# Here I drop the NaN (all those values that have special character in them)


df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.lower())
# convert every value to lower case

df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('é','è'))
# replace operation

print df
```

results in

```
                                      id raw_value manual_raw_value
1   000b08e3-4129-4fd2-8ec0-23d00fe38a45        ok               ok
4   0070ae6a-944b-4549-a229-00301cc96e29      6456            14762
5   00827aad-f737-4ec6-9881-988982662ad8        ht               ht
6   008796d7-b21e-4b91-854f-1d163e336c05    avenue           avenue
7   009dfaa8-5343-4345-8619-3010a1f77a03      1740             1740
8   00ad9cc7-c048-4d82-aa90-727d6eede4ea     total            total
9   00c46967-ee13-40ac-a4b4-4c0cf4186e90        st               st
10  01167f7e-01eb-4033-b62b-92674ba40182        la               la
11  013254c9-4353-45dc-9955-7520474803b7     zèbra            zèbra
```

Comment: thank you for your response. However, 
df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any', inplace = True)  remove all the rows of my file , it keeps only header